# Horizontal listview that expands

Tags: android, android-listview

I am looking for a way to do expandable listview horizontally. So basically, assuming you have a horizontal item, then when you click on it it expands to the right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do a horizontal listview using the android api. There are a few external jars but i would not reley on them as they are no recent commits to their repositories.
**But** you can however do a horizonal scrollview and do your requirement in the onclick listener